# Shorter way to compare two lists and remove values that are in both?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to compare two ArrayLists and remove values from a list if they appear on a second one. Both lists contain the same class: "EditableListItem.

```
ArrayList<EditableListItem> items = new ArrayList<EditableListItem>();
ArrayList<EditableListItem> addedItems = new ArrayList<EditableListItem>();
```

I have written this code, which does the job however I don't feel it's a very good solution.

```
    int remove_n = -1;
    for(int k=0;k<addedItems.size();k++)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++)
        {
            if(items.get(i).getKey().equals(addedItems.get(k).getKey()))
            {
                remove_n = i;
            }
        }
        if(remove_n > -1)
        {
            items.remove(remove_n);
            remove_n = -1;
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to do this with less lines? Or maybe using some method from ArrayList?

Thanks

Comment: Check the javadoc of `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

To remove all items from a collection that are in another collection, use [`removeAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29).

```
items.removeAll(addedItems);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ArrayList#removeAll(Collection c)`, e.g. `items.removeAll(addedItems)`.

If you want it to run faster, make a HashSet from one collection, then call its `removeAll()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could note down all the array indices (in both arrays) where array elements are the same, and one you iterate thrrough both lists, remove the common elements using

```
items.remove(index);
```

method.

Don't remove without iterating completely through both the arraylists, because when you remove one element, the array indices for all subsequent elements change.

Else, if you would like to do it in one loop itself, as and when you delete the element, decrement your loop variable by one, so that index associativity is maintained for both arraylists.